# Sitecore Add Role In Role using Sitecore Power Shell Extension Script

Tags: powershell, role-management

How can we add RoleToTheRole. For example i want to add ('sitecore\developer') role to the role ('sitecore\test') using power shell script.

In c# with the below code i am able to add role to the role

[image]

I tried adding member using like below, with the below syntax i am able to add the role in Members but my requirement is add the role in "Member Of" instead of "Members"

PS master:> Add-RoleMember -Identity 'Test' -Members "developer"

[image]

[image]

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#

[image]

Sitecore Powershell script

```
$rolesarray = [System.Web.Security.Roles]::GetAllRoles()
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$roles = $rolesarray
$indexOptions = [ordered]@{}
foreach($role in $roles) {
    $indexOptions[$role] = $role
}
$role=$indexOptions[0];
$mrole=$indexOptions[0];
$dialogProps = @{
    Parameters = @(

        @{ Name = "parentRole"; Value=$role; Title="Parent role"; Tooltip="List of roles"; Options=$indexOptions; Columns=6;},
        @{ Name = "memberRole"; Value=$mrole; Title="Member role"; Tooltip="List of roles"; Options=$indexOptions; Columns=6;}

    )
    Description = "Add the roles to role"
    Title = "Add the roles to role"
    Width = 700
    Height = 575
    OkButtonName = "Proceed"
    CancelButtonName = "Abort"
    ShowHint = $true
    Icon = [regex]::Replace($PSScript.Appearance.Icon, "Office", "OfficeWhite", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
}
$result = Read-Variable @dialogProps

if($result -ne "ok") {
    Exit
}

if($parentRole -eq $memberRole) {
    Show-Alert -Title "Both the role should not be same!"
}
else
{
if(([Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager]::RolesInRolesSupported) -And (-Not([Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager]::IsRoleInRole([Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role]::FromName($memberRole),[Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role]::FromName($parentRole),$false)) ))
{
[Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager]::AddRoleToRole([Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role]::FromName($memberRole),[Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role]::FromName($parentRole));
Show-Alert -Title "Successfully added"
}
else
{
Show-Alert -Title "Not supported role"
}
}
```

[image]